# How to add a query string to req.url in Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to add a string to a `req.url` in Express.  The string looks like this:

```
?id=someID&product=bag
```

I don't have an access to client html or server. All I get from client it's just a `GET` request without any parameters. So I tried to make middleware which would add query string and then I will parse it like always. The idea was:

```
// Middleware

const addQuery = (req, res, next) => {
    req.url = req.url + `?id=someID&product=bag`;
    next();
}
```

And then in request handler:

```
router.get('/', addQuery, (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.query.id);
    console.log(req.query.product);
});
```

But it gives me `undefined`. I can't use any client side `js` and I can't use server side coding. Not my `origin` sends me this request.

So how to add query string to express request and then successfully parse it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`express` appears to export a middleware called `query` that it uses to parse query strings. Because this middleware is typically called early in the request flow, adding a query string to `req.url` happens "too late".

Here's a workaround that appears to work:

```
const addQuery = (req, res, next) => {
  req.url   = req.url + `?id=someID&product=bag`;
  req.query = null; // if this isn't added, the `query` middleware
                    // will assume the query string is already parsed
  next();
}

app.get('/', addQuery, express.query(), (req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

**EDIT**: as @wlh rightfully suggests, `addQuery` could also modify `req.query` directly:

```
const addQuery = (req, res, next) => {
  req.query.id      = 'someID';
  req.query.product = 'bag';
  next();
}
```

This should work pretty much the same, but much cleaner.

Comment: Out of curiosity, could he not also just update the req.query object within his middleware ? `req.query={id: 'someID', product: 'bag"}`

Comment: @wlh duh, of course that's also possible, and much easier too! :D

Comment: How do I do the same thing with post?   server.post("/sample-redirect", (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, application/json"
    );
    res.header(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "PUT, POST, GET, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    );
    console.log("Request Data : ", req.body);
    return app.render(req, res, "/sample-redirect", {
      sample_data: req.body
    });
  });

Comment: I would like to append the posted data to the URL like /sample-redirect?JSON.stringify(sample_data)